# Angular-route can't find views

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

This is my angular app-file where i add my routing:

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module("CustCMS", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/Index", {
            templateUrl: "~/CustCMS/Views/User/Index.html",
            controller: "IndexController"
        })
        .when("/User/:userid", {
            templateUrl: "~/CustCMS/Views/User/User.html",
            controller: "UserController"
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/Index" });
});
}());
```

I have tried some different ways to enter the templateUrl but i always get this error:

```
 [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: ~/CustCMS/Views/User/Index.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)
```

[image]

What do i have to enter for the templateUrl to find my views?

Comment: have you tried `templateUrl: "/Views/User/Index.html",` ?

Comment: yes. I dosn't work either :(

Answer (score 1):

So i found the answere. Angular can't handle cshtml files so you have to user static views. And becuase of some constraint in visual studio you can't have static views in the views folder so you have to create another folder and add the static views to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

because you are including your `index.html` in some folder. change the **otherwise** route to

```
/CustCMS/Views/User/Index.html.
```